# Socket.io v3 Unsupported protocol version error

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm stuck with the newer version of socket.io. Everything was fine but when I wanted to upgrade to socket.io 3, everything just broke, and currently on the client, I'm getting a 400 HTTP status code with the following JSON response -
`{"code":5,"message":"Unsupported protocol version"}`

Server-side config -

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: config.clientURL,
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      credentials: true,
    },
  });
```

Client-side config -

```
const socket = io(backendURL, {
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

I've tried very many things and redeployed many times but the error didn't go away.

For reference, I've these github repos -

Client in `react.js` - [GitHub repo](https://github.com/41y08h/TicTacToe)

Server in `nodeJs` and `socket.io.js` - [GitHub repo](https://github.com/41y08h/TicTacToeAPI)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Looks like there may be a mismatch between versions of your socket.io-client and socket.io server.

First, update the servers with allowEIO3 set to true (added in socket.io@3.1.0)

```js
const io = require("socket.io")({
  allowEIO3: true // false by default
});
```

After you've upgraded the socket.io-client (latest right now is 3.1.1), you can set it back, or remove it since default is false

```js
const io = require("socket.io")({
  allowEIO3: false
});
```

Comment: Though I upgraded both to 3.1.1, error messages still persisted. Just resolved after use allowEIO3. I have no idea.

Comment: thank you sir, u saved me a lot of time

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Altough my socket client and server versions were same. Just updated both to highest of major version. 
Not sure what caused it. The difference was just that I had setup server-app on a new AWS instance, while my react-app was still on the older one.

Answer (score 0):

I install old version by

```
npx create-nuxt-app@2.15.0
```

It will install nuxt with express.js in one project.
Then update npm packages by commands:

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm i
```

And socket.io goes well between nuxt and socket.io on server