# Not a constructor error if i upgrade socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io in my code base(node.js), which has version 2.2.0 and below is the code:

```
const SocketIoServer = require('socket.io');
const io = new SocketIoServer({ path: baseuri + '/socket.io' });
```

And its working fine.

Now if upgrade socket.io to latest version(4.4.1) i am getting the following error

```
const io = new SocketIoServer({ path: baseUri + '/socket.io' });
               ^
    
    TypeError: SocketIoServer is not a constructor
```

Is there any changes needed after upgrade. I went through docs but i coudn't get anything related to this. Please provide your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

```
const { Server: SocketIoServer} = require('socket.io');
```

And that should fix it

You can check the documentation for this change here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-initialization/#standalone

Comment: Receiving error {"code":5,"message":"Unsupported protocol version"}

Comment: Just a question when you upgraded did you also upgrade the socket.io-client, they both need to be on the same version

Comment: You can also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66047026/socket-io-v3-unsupported-protocol-version-error